# Connection error to MongoDB: object has no attribute 'getitem'

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

When trying to connect to MongoDB , I'm experiencing an error

How can I solve this?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:/MongoDB-U/Python/Codes/Try.py", line 17, in 
>       print (item['name'])
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Code:

```
import pymongo

from pymongo import MongoClient

connection = MongoClient('localhost',27017)

db = connection.test
names = db.things
item  = things.find_one()

print (item['name'])
```

Comment: item is `None`, the equivalent of `null` in python. Likely your query to mongo returned no results.

Comment: I have a collection names things in Mongo

Comment: import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db = connection.test
names = db.things

item  = things.find_one()


print (item['name'])

Comment: that doesn't change the fact that `find_one` is returning `None`. Is there anything in that collection?

Comment: Yes the collection has one entry {name : "Will"}

Comment: Added Code in  question @JohnnyHK   Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Giving me error like this                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/MongoDB-U/Python/Codes/Try.py", line 14, in <module>
    item  = things.find_one()
NameError: name 'things' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a `names` collection variable but then using a `things` collection variable in your `find_one` call. It should be:

```
db = connection.test
things = db.things
item  = things.find_one()

print (item['name'])
```